# Default taxonomy view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

how can I edit the taxonomy view ? I'm talking about the view that is automatically created for each taxonomy term.

I noticed the taxonomy Views is disabled in Views:
Default Node view: taxonomy_term  (default)

However it is used emulate Drupal core's handling of taxonomy/term.

Than I was wondering where the default view for taxonomy is defined and if I can change it from back-end or I do need to edit a php template.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I edit the taxonomy view ? I'm talking about the view that is automatically created for each taxonomy term.
>   I noticed the taxonomy Views is disabled in Views

Views, in some cases, alter the output of a module; that is what it does when you enable the tracker view, and the Tracker module is enabled (see http://example.com/tracker, or http://example.com/user/1/tracker).
This is also what I does with the taxonomy terms list; once you enable the view, the output of the taxonomy module will be replaced with a view. If you don't enable the taxonomy view, you will not able to change the output of the taxonomy module, if not writing a custom module.

Comment: so you are saying that if I enable the disabled taxonomy view in Views I'm replacing and not just simulating the core taxonomy view ?

Comment: You would not replace the core taxonomy view if you would change the path used by Views for that view. It's not something I would suggest to do; I just mean that if there is a page output from module that is being replaced from a view, and you want both the output from the module and the view, then you need to change the path associated with the view.